# How to get distinct data from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Function of getting the distinct value of employee  :

```
 function WeeklyEmplyoee($type)
     {
      $role=Roles::pluck('name','id');
      $items= DB::table('login_activity');


      if($type == 'active')
      {
        $items= $items->whereBetween('login_time',[date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' -7 day')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' +1 day'))]);
      }
      elseif($type == 'inactive')
      {
        $items= $items->whereNotBetween('login_time',[date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' -7 day')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' +1 day'))]);
      }

      $items=$items->orderBy('login_time','desc')->distinct('user_id')->get();


      return view('admin.loginactivity.active-inactive',compact('items','role'));
     }
```

How to get distinct value .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function WeeklyEmplyoee($type)
{
    $role = Roles::pluck('name','id');
    $items = DB::table('login_activity')->distinct();


    if ($type == 'active') {
        $items = $items->whereBetween('login_time',[date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' -7 day')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' +1 day'))]);
    }
    elseif ($type == 'inactive') {
        $items = $items->whereNotBetween('login_time',[date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' -7 day')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' +1 day'))]);
    }

    $items = $items->orderBy('login_time','desc')->get(['user_id']);


    return view('admin.loginactivity.active-inactive', compact('items','role'));
}
```